# Runnable for myLocationOverlay.runOnFirstFix not called and getMyLocation() is null

Tags: osmdroid, mylocationoverlay

I am trying to get the current location and display it on a OSMdroid map inside an Android application. But I get no location and a `Runnable` that is supposed to be called the first time the location is found is never called.

I have tried different providers, permissions are all enabled and GPS location, too.

```
private void getCurrentLocation() {
    GpsMyLocationProvider provider = new GpsMyLocationProvider(this);
    provider.addLocationSource(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    provider.addLocationSource(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationNewOverlay(provider, mMapView);
    myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
    myLocationOverlay.setDrawAccuracyEnabled(true);

    myLocationOverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // never reaches this point
            Timber.i("runOnFirstFix");
        }
    });

    mMapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay);

    if (myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation() == null) {
        // this shows up
        Timber.i("Location not retrieved");
    }
}
```

I understand that the location might not be found as soon as the overlay is added, but I don't understand why the `Runnable` doesn't work

Comment: runtime permissions? and did you ever get a fix?

Comment: Yes, the user is asked to grant permissions at runtime. Still investigating. Might be some bug in newer version of osmdroid or Android

Comment: `GPS_PROVIDER` won't work indoors and `NETWORK_PROVIDER` might need a SIM card. But you could install some "fake GPS" app from the Play Store just to test that your app should work if a location were received.